# Poisson process with deterministic element - construction of a probability law

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $N(t)\sim P(\lambda t)$ describe an arrival process, suppose that every $n$th arrival is marked. Let $B(t)$ be the total number of marked arrivals in the interval $[0,t]$. What is the probability function of $B(t)$?

$$
P(B(t)=k) = (P(T_{n}<t))^kP(T_{n}>t), \,\, k=0,1,2,...
$$
where $P(T_{n}<t) = 1- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{-\lambda t} \lambda^k t^k}{k!}. $

Is it right?

Comment: Maybe we can go back to basics. The probability that $B(t)=0$ is $\sum_0^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$. The probability that $B(t)=1$ is $\sum_n^{2n-1}e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So you mean that $P(B(t)=k) = \sum_{k=kn}^{(k+1)n-1}e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$?
Basically, $P(B(t)=k) = P(T_{kn} < t) P(T_{k(n+1)}>t)$?

Comment: I agree with the first, not necessarily with the second. The events whose probabilities you multiplied do not look independent to me.

Comment: I do not recognize the distribution as a "known" one.

Comment: Correcting my previous comment: $P(B(t)=k) = P(T_{kn} < t) P(T_{n(k+1)}-T_{kn}>t) = P(T_{kn} < t) P(T_{n}>t)$?. Is this version correct? Thank you very much!

Comment: This looks right, we now do have independence.